# What's the difference between 〜以上は and 〜からには

Tags: grammar

The textbook I'm currently using defines both of these grammar points as: 〜のだから、絶対にする／しないのが当然だ

What is the difference between the two grammar points, can they be used interchangeably like the following:

自分でやると言った**からには**、最後まで責任を持ってやってください。
vs
自分でやると言った**以上は**、最後まで責任を持ってやってください。

If they can be used interchangeably, is there any nuance I should be aware of?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do 以上 and 以下 include the number preceding them?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/do-%e4%bb%a5%e4%b8%8a-and-%e4%bb%a5%e4%b8%8b-include-the-number-preceding-them)

Comment: I voted to close by mistake. Sorry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're basically the same.  It means, "Hold onto your responsibilities until the bitter end because your word is your bond."

If there's some slight difference in nuance, then the second sentence would be more officious.  If two people, a boss and his or her subordinate were talking, it would be kind of an unfriendly admonishment of the worker's poor performance.  If two people know one another as friends, then maybe they would say 'kara'.  It would still be said in a strict tone, though.  So, just the setting: friendly vs business setting.

You could say `以上は` with friends, but if you use that then the atmosphere would become very serious.  If you used `からには`, it's not serious.  You know, you might say it to a child who played a video game but didn't clean, and he didn't do the cleaning part.  So, it still sounds like you're talking down, a little, if you say `からには`.