# Expressing  "not greater/less than" and "greater/less than or equal to"

Tags: phrase-requests, mathematics

I'm having trouble coming up with a way of saying "not greater than 0" and "not less than 0".

Would the following sentences be natural/grammatical? If not, in what ways can the following be expressed?

- greater than 0/less than 0

  > 0より大きい/0より小さい
- greater than or equal to 0/less than or equal to 0

  > 0以上である/0以下である
- not greater than 0/not less than 0

  > 0以上ではない/0以下ではない

Space ALC says that [greater than or equal](http://eow.alc.co.jp/greater+than+equal/UTF-8/) is `～以上で` and [less than or equal](http://eow.alc.co.jp/less+than+equal/UTF-8/) is `以下の`.

I thought that `以上` meant "above" and `以下` "below". If that's the case, is there any way to tell that usage and their usage as "greater/less than or equal" apart?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do 以上 and 以下 include the number preceding them?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/do-%e4%bb%a5%e4%b8%8a-and-%e4%bb%a5%e4%b8%8b-include-the-number-preceding-them)

Comment: indeed it is very similar...oh well, other people will hopefully be able to find it more easily next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways of answering this question.  Are you looking for mathematical terms for 'not greater/less than' and 'greater/less than', or ways of expressing this in more general conversation?

Mathematically, the greater than symbol ＞ is pronounced 大なり（だいなり） and the less than symbol ＜ is pronounced 小なり（しょうなり）. The greater than or equal sign ≧ is pronounced 大なりイコール and the less than or equal sign ≦ is pronounced 小なりイコール.

In terms of daily conversation, I think you pretty much have it. より大きい and より小さい do *not* include the value being used for the comparison, while 以下 and 以上 do.  Although keep in mind that this is a dictionary definition, and my experience is that in normal daily conversation they tend to be used a bit interchangeably without paying too much attention to that specific detail.

Also there is the term 未満（みまん）, which you can use as a 'less than' term that doesn't include the number being used.  Example: １８歳未満禁止（じゅうはっさいみまんきんし） means 'no admittance to those under 18'.