# How to express "more than something"?

Tags: set-phrases

I was wondering if there is a form I can use to express "more than X".

For example, "reading *more than* 200 pages a day is a challenge". Or maybe something like, "reading *as much as* 200 pages a day is a challenge", or "I have never read so many pages before".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do 以上 and 以下 include the number preceding them?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/do-%e4%bb%a5%e4%b8%8a-and-%e4%bb%a5%e4%b8%8b-include-the-number-preceding-them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd probably write them like:

> - 一日に200ページ以上を読むのは大変だ。
>     "Reading more than 200 pages a day is difficult."
>     ("200 or more pages a day" but I'm not sure the difference of a single page matters here.)
> - 一日に200ページも読むのは大変だ。
>     "Reading as much as 200 pages a day is difficult."
> - これまでこんなページ数を読んだことがなかった。
>     "Until now I haven't read such a number of pages."

According to Chocolate's comment, it looks like `も` is better than `ほど` for expressing a degree here. According to Edict, the second sense of `も` is:

> 2: about (emphasizing an upper limit), as much as, even

You could probably use `難しい／チャレンジ／大チャレンジ` etc in place of `大変`. `読むことは大変` could also be used instead of `読むのは（が）大変` I think.

I have no idea if these sentences are natural or not so please consider this a temporal answer...

Comment: I'd say '一日に２００ページ"も"読むのは大変だ' for the 2nd example

Comment: @Chocolate thanks! I made so many mistakes in that sentence >_<. I didn't know `も` could be used that way, is it just that `も` sounds more natural or is `ほど` incorrect in some way?

Comment: @cyper san, I think 'こんなに' in「今まで'こんな(に)'(+たくさん/多くのetc.)…を…したことはない」(like in your 3rd example sentence) can be replaced with 'これほど'.  But 'ほど' in「一日に200ページ'ほど'読むのは…」sounds like 'about.'

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks that 一日に200ページ以上読むのは大変だ sounds more natural (correct?) than 一日に200ページ以上**を**読むのは大変だ? I never studied Japanese grammar formally, so I don't know the rules, but I think this is because ページ is a counter, not a noun, i.e. there is an implicit 一日に（本などを）200ページ以上読むのは大変だ。Slightly off topic, sorry...

Comment: @dainichi I asked a couple of people, they basically said it was natural with or without `を` (though more common without). They said that with the `を` it was an objective which makes the speaker think it depends on what the reader is reading how difficult it is, and without `を` it's an adverbial usage which focuses on pages in general.