# Is 以降 inclusive?

Tags: time

If I say:

> 16日[以降]{いこう}参加できません。

It means I cannot participate after the 16th.

However, what about on the 16th?  Is it also implied that I cannot participate on the 16th either?  Or, that I can participate on the 16th, but not after?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/do-%E4%BB%A5%E4%B8%8A-and-%E4%BB%A5%E4%B8%8B-include-the-number-preceding-them

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it is inclusive. All the similar phrases that use 以 are inclusive: 以内、以前、以上、以下、以来. However, unfortunately a lot of people do not know this and use them carelessly without thinking.

If you wanted to express "After the 16th but not including it", you could say:

> 16日の翌日から参加できません。

However, I would be more inclined to say:

> 17日以降参加できません。

Comment: I trust your answer. By the way how would you express "After the 16th but not including it" ?

Comment: In your particular example, you could say: 16日の翌日から参加できません。However, I would be more inclined to say 17日以降参加できません。

Comment: Another way to say “I cannot participate after Feb. 16, exclusive” is 16日までしか参加できません: “I can participate only until Feb. 16, inclusive.”